# How to get such header title and search input in Google search for website

Tags: seo, google-search

How to get such header title and search input in Google search for website like below:

[image: Google search for 'stack overflow', showing a search field and 6 additional links]

I am doing my website with core PHP (not any CMS like WordPress, Drupal etc.). So please help me to get such a result in Google.

Comment: Not able to understand your question. Do you want to create Html like google search results or need to get search results from google?

Answer (score 1):

This is called `Sitelinks`.

Check it out here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en

It's an Google automated process and you can't do much to control it. Although a google search on "how to get sitelinks" gives you plenty of results on how to get them, for example, [here](https://www.hochmanconsultants.com/how-to-get-google-sitelinks/), or [here](http://www.bloggingspell.com/google-sitelinks/).

Or perhaps you can [purchase them](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375416?hl=en) under your AdWords advertisement.

As far as I know, it is much related to PHP. It's more on Search Engine Optimization (SEO).